# How to capture user data

Tags: javascript

I can cut and paste with the best of 'em, and using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions I created a map that allows users to select from dropdowns the travelMode to and from 10 MetroRail sites at http://www.helpasneeded.com/test-googlemapstai.

What I don't see is how to allow users to enter information, e.g., date and time of travel or unique start and end locations. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Cutting and pasting is not exactly the best way to learn how to program...

Comment: Please add code context

Comment: @Doorknob, I appreciate your point, but there are many ways to learn languages ... sit down and learn to conjugate estar, or simply listen, cut, and paste "¿Cómo estás?"

Comment: @morisette not sure what context you mean, thought the page was self evident, but perhaps it isn't so. I want a tool to calculate travel times between two predetermined locations by different modes of travel at dates and times the user chooses. Is that what you mean by context?

Answer (score 0):

I should not answer this, yet I will.

One... you need some DOM, HTML for a user to Input Data and then to Use Javascript to pull that data.

http://codeacademy.com much better than overly technical code documents.

Comment: start at HTML/CSS then go to Javascript